# Setting up OpenCV for C++ in VIsual Studio Code in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, cmake

There may be several similar questions, I read most of them but it did not sovle my problem. This is my first time setting this up. I will sum up what I have done.

First I  installed OpenCV from source (both opencv and opencv_contrib) (version 4.5.2)  [following this link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/). After that I find out I need CMakeLists.txt and I put this content inside it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(opeet)

find_package( OpenCV 4 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(opeet moje.cpp)
target_link_libraries( opeet ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

This CMake file says this:

```
Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found suitable version "4.5.2", minimum required is "4")
```

So I suppose it found OpenCV properly.

When I had run this program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
   std::cout<<"hahahahha"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I got error: `opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp not found`.

Then I made little change in my directories organization. When I installed OpenCV it installed in directory:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2
```

I moved directory  `opencv2` to `include` (so `opencv4` is deleted).

So now directory for OpenCV is:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2
```

Now program in the above compiles fine.

But now if I add this line (just declaring variable) `cv::Mat q;`, when I compile it gives me error:

```
/home/faris/Desktop/Opeet/moje.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
/home/faris/Desktop/Opeet/moje.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
```

Now my agony starts. I can't solve this. I tried a lot of things. I tried adding path to `c_cpp_properties.json` but it did not help. I will post files from `.vscode` so maybe there is some mistake.

`c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    }
]
}
```

**I would really appreciate** if someone could help me with this, I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Your tasks.json does not seem correct at all for building using a CMake generated Makefile.

Comment: What should I change? I generated this by i,structions of Visual Studio code official page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

Comment: It works when i put in cmd this (I am located in the directory of my c++ program):
`cmake .`
`make`

Why it works like this, and not from VS Code?

Comment: I don't know the correct settings for tasks.json to support cmake but currently its not using cmake at all and trying to build the active file with no libraries.